# How to insert symbols while key press in focused textbox using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Example

```
<textarea name="test"></textarea>
```

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) { 
    if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
        var focused = document.activeElement; 
        $(focused).append("test string");  
        return false;    
    }
});
```

Find focused textbox / content editable div and append string by using jquery. please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: $(document.activeElement) check if its a text area/text box and then just set its val or append it

Comment: seems to work for me: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/v5bosqo4/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't want it to trigger on any other Element?

Use `if (document.activeElement.name == "test")` to do so:

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27/*ESC*/) {
    if (document.activeElement.name == "test") {
      var focused = document.activeElement;
      $(focused).append("test string");
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="test"></textarea>
```